# plists - iOS development (NSString)

Tags: iphone, plist

I've created a plist called "hospitals", inserted first row as an array with three items as strings.

what's wrong with my code:

```
NSArray *hospitals = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Hospitals" ofType:@"plist"]];
    NSString *first = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [hospitals objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSLog(@"%@",first);
```

This is giving me (null)  as a result!

Answer (score 1):

Either the property list file doesn't exist (check the "Copy Resources" build phase of your target), has a different name (note that iOS' file system is case sensitive), isn't a property list at all (maybe it has a syntax error), isn't readable or the property list's root isn't an array, but a dictionary.

If `hospitals == nil` either of the above is the problem.

Comment: -i found the plist in my (copy resources)
-i took care of the case sensitive thing too,
- the plist root IS an array !
 i dunno what's wrong!

& hospitals == nil  is TRUE :S

Comment: @user916316 try to clean the project and build it again.

Comment: cleaning didn't help either!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *errorDesc = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Hospitals" ofType:@"plist"]];
NSMutableDictionary *properties = (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];
NSArray *hospitals = (NSArray *)[properties valueForKey:@"names"]; 
NSString *first = [hospitals objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@",first);
```

Comment: Put here the content of your plist, please.

Comment: names    -   array  -  (3 items)
item 0   -   string   -  first
item 1   -   string   - second
item 2   -  string    - third

Comment: this actually worked ! thnx alot! but do u know why didn't my first form of code worked?

Comment: Because your plist is an NSDictionary containing one object of type NSArray called names.

Comment: Yes, fichek is right! So if there are no more problems, close the topic